# Kubernetes Continuous Deployment

Tags: kubernetes, spinnaker

I know continuous deployment can be done via spinnaker like Blue/Green, Canary Deployment etc 
but my question how does it differ from other GitOps tools like WeaveWorks Flux ? 
Does both solve the same problem ? or Do we need both tools in conjunction ?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in "[The GitOps Pipeline - Part 2](https://www.weave.works/blog/the-gitops-pipeline)"

> **[Weave Flux](https://www.weave.works/oss/flux/)** is a tool that automates the staging and release of containers to Kubernetes, as well as services, deployments, network policies and even Istio routing rules. Flux is therefore ‘glue’ that maps all the relationships between code, services and running clusters.
>
> **It can be seen as a leaner, Kubernetes-native alternative to [Spinnaker](http://blog.armory.io/what-is-immutable-infrastructure/)**.